# Login Community

Tags: community, community-builder

How to put the standard login template in Spanish?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you add / change and set defaults on the sites page for this community.

When you add a language you can then rearrange their order and set as default.

Here:

- Click Site Configuration | Languages on the Overview tab.
- Click Add Languages.
- Select the languages you want to add to your site.
- If necessary, reorder the list as you want it to appear in any language selector.
- Save your changes.

To set default:

- Click Site Configuration | Languages on the Overview tab.
- Select a language in the Default Site Language drop-down list.

Reference [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=siteforce_languages_default.htm&type=5)